# bq extract - BigQuery error in extract operation: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, bq

I am trying to export a table from BigQuery to google storage using the following command within the console:

```
bq --location=<hidden> extract --destination_format CSV --compression GZIP --field_delimiter "|" --print_header=true <project>:<dataset>.<table> gs://<airflow_bucket>/data/zip/20200706_<hidden_name>.gzip
```

I get the following error :

> BigQuery error in extract operation: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Here is some information about the said table

```
Table ID    <HIDDEN> 
Table size 6,18 GB
Number of rows   25 854 282 
Created 18.06.2020, 15:26:10 
Table expiration     Never 
Last modified 14.07.2020, 17:35:25 
Data location    EU
```

What I'm trying to do here, is extract this table into google storage. Since the table is > 1 Gb, then it gets fragmented... I want to assemble all those fragments into one archive, into a google cloud storage bucket.

What is happening here? How do I fix this?

Note: I've hidden the actual names and locations of the table & other information with the mention  `<hidden>` or `<airflow_bucket>` or `:.

---

`

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason behind this, the documentation gives the following syntax for the `bq extract`

```
> bq --location=location extract \
> --destination_format format \
> --compression compression_type \
> --field_delimiter delimiter \
> --print_header=boolean \ project_id:dataset.table \ gs://bucket/filename.ext
```

I removed `location=<bq_table_location>` and it works on principle. Except I had to add a wildcard and I end up having multiple compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data), you are getting the error due to the 1 Gb file size limit.

Currently it is not possible to accomplish what you want without adding an additional step, either with [concatenating on Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose), or using a Batch Job, on [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs) as an example.

There are some [Google-provided batch templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch) that export data from BigQuery to GCS, but none with the CSV format, so you would need to touch some code in order to do it on Dataflow.